# Continue WinHTTP connection after write shutdown

Tags: php, c++, windows, apache, winhttp

I'm using WinHTTP to send data to a web server script and in some cases I need the server to kill the incoming data (as it is not required) but still return a response to the client app. I'm using `stream_socket_shutdown(STREAM_SHUT_RD)` from the server end to end the incoming data, then sending a response back as normal. The problem lies with WinHTTP, I get a negative response back from `WinHttpWriteData()` as expected and stop sending data but when I call `WinHttpReceiveResponse()` it returns false and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_WINHTTP_CONNECTION_ERROR`.

Is there a way to perhaps reset the internal error condition for WinHTTP? Or another way to receive the response after the connection has been broken by the server?

Thanks,
J

Comment: I don't think you can just shutdown a socket in the middle of a HTTP request and expect everything to work; I'm pretty sure this breaks the protocol specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you kill the connection from the server side, the receive on the client will fail.  This is how WinHTTP is designed to work.

Can't your server just discard unwanted incoming data?

Why is your client still sending when the server is expecting to send it a response?  Perhaps the protocol implied in your HTTP usage can be adjusted to reduce sending of unwanted data from the client in this scenario.

Comment: The connection is not totally killed, just the read channel (write from client), I was hoping that would only fail the WinHttpWriteData() call and not the whole connection. The server can (and does) discard the unwanted data but sometimes it can be several MB and it would be more efficient to stop the data being sent in the first place. The factor that decides if the data is not required is an HTTP header so it really does need to send back a response straight away.